# Ant design dark Mode toggle

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I am able to toggle to dark mode. However,when I toggle back to light mode css doesn't seem to be hot reloading.

Following is my code

```
//ThemeContext.jsx
const DarkTheme = lazy(() => import("./dark-theme"));
const LightTheme = lazy(() => import("./light-theme"));

export const ThemeContext = createContext(null);

export const ThemeContextApp = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
  const [theme, handleToggle] = useTheme();
  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme }} {...rest}>
      <Switch
        checkedChildren="Dark Mode"
        unCheckedChildren="Light Mode"
        checked={theme === "dark"}
        onChange={(checked) => {
          handleToggle(checked);
        }}
      />
      <Suspense fallback={<span />}>
        {theme === "dark" ? <DarkTheme /> : <LightTheme />}
      </Suspense>

      {children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

This is my index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
// import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import { store } from "./app/store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.min.css";
import { ThemeContextApp } from "./Components/Theme/ThemeContext";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ThemeContextApp>
        <App />
      </ThemeContextApp>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

This is my dark theme

```
//DarkTheme.jsx

import React from "react";
import "./dark-theme.css";
const DarkTheme = () => <></>;

export default DarkTheme;
```

This is my light theme

```
//LightTheme.jsx
import React from "react";
import "./light-theme.css";

const LightTheme = () => {
  console.log("light theme loading");
  return <></>;
};
export default LightTheme;
```

This is my useThemeHook

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const useTheme = () => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState("light");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (window.localStorage.getItem("theme")) {
      let localStorageItem = window.localStorage.getItem("theme");
      setTheme(localStorageItem);
    } else {
      window.localStorage.setItem("theme", theme);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    let localStorageItem = window.localStorage.getItem("theme");
    if (localStorageItem !== theme) {
      window.localStorage.setItem("theme", theme);
    }
  }, [theme]);

  const handleToggle = (checked) => {
    if (checked) {
      setTheme("dark");
    } else {
      setTheme("light");
    }
    // return window.location.reload();
  };

  return [theme, handleToggle];
};
```

When I switch to Dark Mode , it is fine. However when I switch back to Light Mode, it requires me to refresh the page for the light theme css to kick in. When I checked the console,  the component is rendered, but not the light theme css

[image]

As you can see here, the console.log message of the light mode works too but the css is not getting refreshed

[image]

Please kindly advise

Thank you

EDIT:

This is my Full code : https://codesandbox.io/s/antdesignlight-darktheme-gqwlyz?file=/src/components/UseTheme.jsx

Answer (score 0):

Try storing your `checked` value with `useState` like this:

```js
export const ThemeContextApp = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
  const [theme, handleToggle] = useTheme();
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme }} {...rest}>
      <Switch
        checkedChildren="Dark Mode"
        unCheckedChildren="Light Mode"
        onChange={(checked) => {
          handleToggle(!checked);
          setChecked(!checked);
        }}
      />
      <Suspense fallback={<span />}>
        {theme === "dark" ? <DarkTheme /> : <LightTheme />}
      </Suspense>

      {children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Additional resource: https://dommagnifi.co/2020-12-03-toggle-state-with-react-hooks/

Comment: Hi, i tried your way, it is still not working.